# How many times a button is clicked?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

How to know how many times a button is clicked in pyqt ? where ui is prepared in qt-designer and imported into python as .ui file.

Example:

```
self.submit.clicked.connect(self.submit_application)
```

and in

```
def submit_application:
```

how to know that submit.clicked has happened for n number of times ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your *self* is a parent widget, you may add a counter member which will be updated any time the slot is called. Something like:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        ... #Your widget initialization, including *sumbit* button
        self.submit.clicked.connect(self.submit_application)
        self._submit_counter = 0

     def submit_application(self):
        self._submit_counter += 1
        ... # Rest of slot handling
```

Comment: But when I added def __init__(), I gave def __init__(self, parent=None)... should i remove it ?